# What is wrong in the following comparing and object property implementation it returns just 2 value (JS)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to check if the first array includes the object that has the same id as the first element in the second array. Then for that object in the first array add the following 2 property values.
I tried the following but it returns only an array of that new values instead of returning the full first array of objects that includes that modified object with new properties.

```
 products = products
        .filter(item => item.id === productsByTags[0].id)
        .map(item => (item.tags = 'shoes'), (item.keywords = 'black'))
```

How can I get the full array of objects where those 2 new properties, values are added to that object which has the same id based on above condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a new objectby spreading the actual object and two new properties.

```
.map(item => ({ ...item, tags: 'shoes', keywords: 'black' }))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer what if there are more objects in the second array and I need to match them based on Id and after that add the property inside the first array from second array...

Comment: what is the first and second array?

Comment: products and productsByTags. The only difference between them is that second one contains those tags properties and it's filtered. So for the case where there are more than one objects in the productByTags the solution in my question will not work. Is there way to compare those 2 arrays and for each matching object with id add tags property with its value from productsByTag into the products array of objects?

Comment: do you have an example? probably with a new question?

Comment: I can repost a new question only after 30 minutes. Will let you know once post again but the data model is the same as in the above question with the same codebase.Just productsByTags[0].id  part is wrong it dynamically should check each id match for each object then add that property for each of them from productByTag arrays objects to the products matching objects

Comment: i think it is a bit more complicate, because of the filtering, you need pick corresponding information from `productsByTags`. do you have some arrays with data? and the wanted result of it?

Comment: Here is the new posted question with the all related details.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64145214/how-to-compare-for-based-on-the-all-common-object-ids-and-add-the-property-insid

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is that both .filter and .map return new arrays. So once you have filtered, you have already removed all items that do not match your check. If you move it all into a single map, you can mutate only the items that you want to while still returning the none mutated items as well.

```
products = products.map(item => {
    let newItem = {...item};
    if(item.id === productsByTags[0].id){
      newItem.tags = 'shoes';
      newItem.keywords = 'black';
    }
    return newItem;
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
products = products
        .filter(item => item.id === productsByTags[0].id)
        .map(item => {
  item.tags = 'shoes'; 
  item.keywords = 'black';
  return item;
});
```

Post filtering the data you were trying to add the new properties to object so you should return the object to map to return you array of objects.